# Change Django Template Inheritance Dynamically?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a template with the following: `{% extends "main/main-template.html" %}`
 I also want a template with the exact same thing, only instead it `{% extends "main/main-template-quick.html" %}` It seems like a violation of DRY to just copy and paste the same code into a new file, just so I can change the template. Is there any way to select the super-template dynamically?

If not, is there a good way to do the following: Reuse the same `{% block %}` and its content with a different template. At the same time, not violating DRY.

I'm also open to other template languages that may be able to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you [check the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends) you'll see that `extends` accepts a variable too.

> {% extends variable %} uses the value of variable. If the variable
>   evaluates to a string, Django will use that string as the name of the
>   parent template.

So you can easily determine the appropiate base template in your view and pass it to your template.

And if you want to reuse a chunk of html in different contexts than the [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) tag is your friend.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to choose the name based on a boolean, since I believe it has to be the first thing in the file.

Comment: I think i don't understand your problem exactly but what you can do is something along these lines: ```template_name = 'main.html' if x else 'alt.html'``` where x is your boolean.

Comment: for booleans, you can use `yesno` directly in the template. {% extends boolean_value|yesno:"template_if_true.html,template_if_false.html" %}

Answer (score 2):

Django allows for display the parent templates block content using [`{{ block.super}}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance).

This allows you to insert the parent's block contents.

```
{% block content %}
  {{ block.super }}
{% endblock content %}
```

`block.super` was designed to allow you to

> **Reuse the same {% block %} and its content with a different template.**